# grunt-contrib-concat concat goal sourcemap option is not working (windows)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

When running grunt concat the console says my source map is created, but the source map is not present on my file system.

My plugin configuration in my Gruntfile:

```
  grunt.config('concat',{
    scripts: {
      src: [
        grunt.config.get('pkg.src') + '/scripts/vendor/underscore*.js',
        grunt.config.get('pkg.src') + '/scripts/vendor/jquery*.js',
        grunt.config.get('pkg.src') + '/scripts/vendor/angular-*.js',
        grunt.config.get('pkg.src') + '/scripts/vendor/*.js',
        grunt.config.get('pkg.src') + '/scripts/source/main.js',
        grunt.config.get('pkg.src') + '/scripts/source/services/httpHelper.js',
        grunt.config.get('pkg.src') + '/scripts/source/**/*.js'
      ], 
      dest: 'static/server/scripts/app.js',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      }
    },
    styles: {
      src: [
        grunt.config.get('pkg.src') + '/styles/vendor/**/*.css',
        grunt.config.get('pkg.src') + '/styles/source/**/*.css'
      ],
      dest: 'static/server/styles/app.css'
    },
  });
```

Console output:

```
C:\workspace\someproject>grunt concat
Running "concat:scripts" (concat) task
Source map static/server/scripts/app.js.map created.
File static/server/scripts/app.js created.

Running "concat:styles" (concat) task
File static/server/styles/app.css created.

Done, without errors.
```

NOTE: I am using Windows 7, Node v0.12.0, Grunt v0.4.5, grunt-cli v0.1.13, and grunt-contrib-concat 0.5.1.